# Is it possible to leave a variable blank/null in a module and define it after it's being called in main.tf?

Tags: terraform

I'm in the process of learning Terraform and I get the general idea that modules are meant to be re-usable. With that, I'm trying to set a variable to be empty/null in the module itself and have it be defined after being called in my main.tf file for the project I'm working on.

For example:
in my Module VPC **main.tf** I have

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc
}
```

in my Module VPC **variables.tf** I have

```
variable "vpc" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}
```

In my root directory where I actually want to define my code for project A, I have tried this in both variables.tf (formatted correctly) and terraform.tfvars (shown below)

```
vpc = "10.0.0.0/16"
```

This is so that project A uses that vpc subnet, but if I have a different project (and therefor different files of main.tf, variables.tf, etc) I can set the variable to a different subnet but still keeping the Module itself clean/easily re-usable.

Comment: And what is the issue here? Have you actually tried running the code? Also, you don't have to provide a default value at all, so `default = null` is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`default` is not mandatory for a variable.

Look at the first example in [the docs for variables](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables) which says:

```
variable "image_id" {
  type = string
}
```